# Android Studio cannot find symbol class / package does not exist /wikitude

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

I hope one of you can help me. Unfortunately I did not find any help on existing issues and I am a newbie in Android Studio. So i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgcB6tMi0qE but didnt get the same result: the backgorund on my phone when I run the project is white instead of video-see-through.
I looked the sample project up from wikitude and wanted to include the camera projects from the sample in the Main Acitivy on my project. When I run the project I get the following Errors:
[Errors][1]

I see that the project cannot load the packages, but I added them in the com path and in an library path. Other imports in the same path have no problem, so I dont understand the problem.
This is the MainActivtiy.java Code:

```
package com.casar.myapplication;

import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.wikitude.NativeStartupConfiguration;
import com.wikitude.WikitudeSDK;
import com.wikitude.camera.CameraManager;
import com.wikitude.camera.CameraManagerListener;
import com.wikitude.common.WikitudeError;
import com.wikitude.common.camera.CameraSettings;
import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectStartupConfiguration;
import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView;
import com.wikitude.common.camera.CameraSettings;
import com.wikitude.samples.WikitudeSDKConstants;
import com.wikitude.samples.camera.CameraSettingsActivity;

import static com.casar.myapplication.R.id;
import static com.casar.myapplication.R.layout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArchitectView architectView;
    private WikitudeSDK wikitudeSDK;
    private CameraManager cameraManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_main);

        this.architectView = (ArchitectView)this.findViewById(id.architectView);
        final ArchitectStartupConfiguration config = new ArchitectStartupConfiguration();
        config.setLicenseKey("*****HERE IS MY KEY*****");
        this.architectView.onCreate( config );

        camera2Enabled = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("enableCamera2", true);

        wikitudeSDK = new WikitudeSDK(this);
        NativeStartupConfiguration startupConfiguration = new NativeStartupConfiguration();
        startupConfiguration.setLicenseKey(WikitudeSDKConstants.WIKITUDE_SDK_KEY);
        startupConfiguration.setCameraPosition(CameraSettings.CameraPosition.BACK);
        startupConfiguration.setCameraResolution(CameraSettings.CameraResolution.AUTO);

        wikitudeSDK.onCreate(getApplicationContext(), this, startupConfiguration);

        cameraManager = wikitudeSDK.getCameraManager();
        cameraManager.setListener(this);

        final TargetCollectionResource targetCollectionResource = wikitudeSDK.getTrackerManager().createTargetCollectionResource("file:///android_asset/magazine.wtc");
        wikitudeSDK.getTrackerManager().createImageTracker(targetCollectionResource, CameraSettingsActivity.this, null);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.architectView.onPostCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        this.architectView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        this.architectView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        this.architectView.onPause();
    }
}
```

Here is the java path structure:
[structure java dir][2]

In other questions I found out that the build:gradle is important, so here is my code of that:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.casar.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation project(path: ':mylibrary')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.wikitude:js:9.4.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.15.0'
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Do you need any other information? I will happily provide you with everything and I hope someone can help!
Greetings!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cov3s.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etb3D.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
You have mentioned   implementation 'com.wikitude:js:9.4.0' so no need to add libs folder. Then sync and try to rebuild the project.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, @Priyanka Rajput ! I deleted the implementation, synced and rebuild but unfortunately I did get the same errors and the same results. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check for the implementations for the same library and try to delete the import statements and reimport again with ctrl+enter.